# i want to fetch result from database by passing array varaible in php

Tags: php

i am getting array from url but and passing it to database but not getting result but when i am use print_r and copy paste the same data then it give the result. But it is not giving me result when is use varaiable.

```
$var=$_GET['var'];

 $var=urldecode(base64_decode($var));

$data = explode(',', $var);

//print_r($data);

$reg_id=$data[0];
$email_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_event,$data[2]);
$event_id=$data[3];

# this is a function to pass the result and it pass through database in where ...
view_ticket($email_id,$event_id,$reg_id);
```

but when i do this it gives pe proper output:-

```
$var=$_GET['var'];
$var=urldecode(base64_decode($var));

$data = explode(',', $var);

//print_r($data);

$reg_id=$data[0];
$email_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_event,$data[2]);
$event_id=$data[3];

# this is a function to pass the result and it pass through database in where ...
view_ticket('example@exmaple.com',$event_id,$reg_id);
```

Comment: What is $_GET['var'] set to? Are you sure it's being set and fetched properly from the URL?

Comment: What does `$email_id` evaluate to? If it is exactly `'example@exmaple.com'`, you should have no problems.

Comment: [The best way to prevent SQL injection is to use prepared statements](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide) (not mysqli_real_escape_string). They separate the data (your parameters) from the instructions (the SQL query string) and doesn't leave any room for the data to contaminate the structure of your query. Prepared statements solve one of the [fundamental problems of application security](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/gentle-introduction-application-security).

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$email_id = trim( mysqli_real_escape_string($db_event,$data[2]) );
```

If you're seeing `example@example.com` in the `print_r()` but it's not working, I'm betting there's just some whitespace in there.